# Correct nginx set up to handle subdomains

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have an nginx instance with the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mySite.com;

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index   index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.mySite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://107.170.102.140:8082;
    }
}
```

When I try to navigate to jenkins.mySite.com, it seems to load the static index.html page. It is not redirecting to my Jenkins (107.170.102.140:8082) instance.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: Depending on the browser and network, I am able to access jenkins subdomain sometimes. It is almost like it is a race condition. I was able to load Jenkins in Chrome, but then instantly switched to IE and it loaded the default static page.

Comment: what is your DNS setup? Do you have DNS records for both mysite.com and jenkins.mysite.com ?

Comment: yes, and we also have a wildcard in there for all subdomains.